# In C#, how to compare JSON strings that differ as strings but are equivalent JSON objects?

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

Is there a way to compare strings which are different as text but give equivalent JSON objects?
The reason I am doing this is I am writing some xUnit integration tests which fetch JSON response returned by live REST API and compare it with JSON strings in text file that represent expected results.

I am using Newtonsoft JSON library, but I can't get this to work. 
For example, following code is always returning false even though strings should give equivalent JSON object.

Here is an example code with comparings that I expected to return true but came out as false:

```cs
        var json1 = "{\"age\":\"10\"}"; // {"age":"10"}
        var json2 = "{\"age\":10}";     // {"age":10}
        var json3 = "{\"age\":10.0}";   // {"age":10.0}

        var result12 = JToken.DeepEquals(JObject.Parse(json1), JObject.Parse(json2));
        var result13 = JToken.DeepEquals(JObject.Parse(json1), JObject.Parse(json3));
        var result23 = JToken.DeepEquals(JObject.Parse(json2), JObject.Parse(json3));
        Console.WriteLine(result12);    // false
        Console.WriteLine(result13);    // false
        Console.WriteLine(result23);    // false
```

Problem here is with the `Number` type and `JToken.DeepEquals()` inability to assume decimal `10.0` is same as `10` which is same as `"10"` etc...
There possibly could be other issues with JToken.DeepEquals() so I am wondering is there some better way to do this kind of compassion?

Comment: These values are *not* equal. In `json1`, the value is a string, `json2`, the value is an int, and `json3`, the value is some sort of float. You will need to convert these values to a common type before comparing them.

Comment: I think they’re actually equivalent in JavaScript, but not in C#.

Comment: I hate to say this but there is a strong code smell to this. You having this question leads me to believe your underlying architecture is very, very wrong.

Comment: @Mr.TA, as I said this code is for integration testing of rest api and is just an example...

Comment: @mlst the response should contain fields of the same type. Floats, ints and strings **shouldn't** be treated as equals for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The JToken.DeepEquals is not used for comparing different types. The docs is [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_DeepEquals.htm)

> Compares the values of two tokens, including the values of all descendant tokens.

For your problems, I suggest to use a base type, and convert all other type to this based type for comparison

The base type could be int. First you parse the json to object (all value is string for example). Then try to convert that string to base type and compare.

Comment: the thing is I'd like to avoid creating strong types for json as it would involve a lot of work and instead just compare json that is returned from rest api to the json I specify in "expected-result.json" file... these could be different strings but should be equivalent json objects